# Changing state of folded item with CLOSED tag in org-mode absorbs the next item

Tags: org-mode

When trying to change the state of an item with `(setq org-log-done 'time)` enabled, they appear in the same line.

I have following org file:

```
* DONE A
  CLOSED: [2020-10-29 Thu 23:35]
* TODO B
```

When my first item is folded (`org-cycle`) and I change the state then it looks like this:

```
* A...* TODO B
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What version? Do `M-x org-version` and edit your question to add it. FWIW, I don't see this with latest Org mode but ISTR that there was a problem like this some time in the past.

Comment: Thanks! You're right, I should have checked the last version. I actually assumed that I have the last version as I used `(package-menu-mark-upgrades)` just before posting here. But seems that the command doesn't upgrade the builtin org package. Thanks a lot for hinting that it was fixed already (sorry I really should have had a closer look myself ).